# How to I create a bubble chart that is aligned in Tableau?

Tags: charts, data-visualization, tableau-api

I want to create a chart with filled bubbles and I want them to be aligned and have equal space in between them. Size depending on measure value. I've tried to create a regular bubble chart but can't get it aligned. Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem?

Bar chart with shapes (can't figure out how to get them aligned)
Packed bubble chart (can't figure out how to get them aligned)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnBD1.jpg)

Want it to look like the one in the bottom of attached image.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome.

1. Put your dimension in the column shelf
2. Put your measure in the size shelf (marks)
3. In the mark shelf, select *Circle* option

You can also adjust other settings, like enlarge the circle's size, add a label, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Although, Armin's answer indeed explains perfectly how to create a bubble chart, I'm not sure whether it tackles the source of the problem based on the image shared by Viktor in his question.
Therefore, Viktor has to edit the bubble chart, changing the "Fit" option to "Standard" (instead of "Entire view"). Next, manually dragging the division between two bubble headers in order to fix the width, as shown in the image below.
[image: bubble chart with fixed width]